# InitWithNavigationBarClass for UINavigationController in a storyboard application

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm currently trying to create a more saturated NavigationBar in a storyboard application. Therefore I want to subclass UINavigationBar but the init method of my NavigationController(rootViewController) isn't called.

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super initWithNavigationBarClass:[CRNavigationBar class] toolbarClass:nil];
    if(self) {
        // Custom initialization here, if needed.
    }

    return self;
}
```

I've already tried to achieve that within my viewDidLoad method but that was leading to rendering bugs (z-order)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to your storyboard. Select your `Navigation Controller Scene`. Beneath your `Navigation Controller`, there is the `Navigation Bar` item. Select it. In the `Utilities Panel` (on the right), select the `Identity Inspector` (3rd tab). Set your subclass of `UINavigationBar` as the `Custom Class`.